converting Python bytearray with hexadecimal to a bytearray with bytes efficiently
I would like to convert a bytearray with ASCII hexadecimal encoded into straight bytes
hex_data = b'010203040a0b0fff'  
data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_data)

But this does not work because the fromhex method expect a string a not a bytearray.
I can add an extra step like:
data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_data.decode())

This shall work, but this is adding an extra processing and one more object to be processed by the GC.
The final objective is to also reverse the bytearray so to create an array and reverse it.
Currently I am using a pure Python programming algorithm that works very well
That is executed several 100th times per seconds and start to consume some significant CPU time.
This shall work with Python 3.7

What is "the GC"?

The extra object will be deleted by its reference count going to zero - the garbage collector is not involved. And its just one in many variables that will be created/deleted in this process. The binascii.a2b_hex function will work with bytes strings but I'm not sure whether its actually any faster.

There is no "extra" processing, the processing is done that needs to be done. If python lacks speed, consider writing it in C.

What does the final result look like?  What is the timing of your method?  Make a [mcve].

do you really need a bytearray?

@Elerium115 "GC" is a very common abbreviation for "Garbage Collector".


The final objective is to also reverse the bytearray so to create an array and reverse it.

You can reverse it without string decoding, but you still need to turn hex ascii-literals into a numbers, in one or another way. And it's still an operation.
>>> hex_data = b'010203040a0b0fff'
>>> bytearray(
...    int(hex_data[i : i + 2], 16)
...    for i in range(len(hex_data) - 2, -2, -2)
... )
bytearray(b'\xff\x0f\x0b\n\x04\x03\x02\x01')

Updated
After testing the my own hypotheses and comments on my answer, I got the following results:
import timeit


def bytearray_decode():
    hex_data = b'010203040a0b0fff'
    data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_data.decode())
    return bytearray(reversed(data))


def bytearray_decode_ascii():
    hex_data = b'010203040a0b0fff'
    data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_data.decode('ascii'))
    return bytearray(reversed(data))


def bytearray_generator():
    hex_data = b'010203040a0b0fff'
    return bytearray(
        int(hex_data[i : i + 2], 16) for i in range(len(hex_data) - 2, -2, -2)
    )


print(max(timeit.repeat(bytearray_decode, number=10, repeat=100000)))
print(max(timeit.repeat(bytearray_decode_ascii, number=10, repeat=100000)))
print(max(timeit.repeat(bytearray_generator, number=10, repeat=100000)))

>>> 0.0002471659972798079
>>> 0.00015083301695995033
>>> 0.00018766699940897524

First, "about 10x slower" for 3rd method does not quite correspond to reality. The test shows: this approach is 25% faster than OP's example.
Second, the faster one is still decode() usage but using ascii encoding parameter instead of default utf-8. It is about 40% faster.

That's about 10x slower than the OP's example, assuming data.reverse() is applied after data = bytearray.fromhex(hex_data.decode()).

I modified your test a bit, having it run through a pre-generated list of 100 random numbers instead of a single constant.  bytearray_decode was ever so slightly faster than bytearray_decode_ascii but probably within the margin of error - but it was 4x faster than bytearray_generator.  The real surprise was substituting data.reverse(); return data for return bytearray(reversed(data)) which sped it up 2x more!

Currently, the code is very close from bytearray_generator, following the proposals, I will replace it by bytearray_decode

The conversion to a string and the following reversal are costly.
A somewhat more performant alternative is to use the int constructor with a base of 16 to convert the hexadecimal bytestring into a big int, and then use the int.to_bytes method to convert the integer to bytes. Since you want the resulting bytearray in reverse order, you would want to use the little-endian byte order:
def to_bytearray(hex_data):
    x = int(hex_data, 16)
    return bytearray(x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'little'))

Benchmark results:
LaurentCarré bytearray(b'\xff\x0f\x0b\n\x04\x03\x02\x01') 0.4208118049427867
tdelaney bytearray(b'\xff\x0f\x0b\n\x04\x03\x02\x01') 0.3885998083278537
AlekseiTrankov bytearray(b'\xff\x0f\x0b\n\x04\x03\x02\x01') 1.6252670958638191
blhsing bytearray(b'\xff\x0f\x0b\n\x04\x03\x02\x01') 0.24237766955047846


I never knew int would take a bytestring as easily as a string.
